# Возвести число в степень, не используя операцию возведения в степень, с помощью цикла for next. VBA

Tags: циклы, vba, for

возможно ли в языке VBA возвести число в степень, не используя операцию возведения в степень, а только с помощью цикла for next? Если да - то как?

Comment: Мат анализ учить надо. Про ряд Тейлора в окрестности точки не забывайте.

Comment: Частный случай ряда Тейлора это разложение Макларена https://www.webmath.ru/poleznoe/formules_8_20.php

Comment: И вы всерьез думаете, что вопрос из контрольной или зачета подразумевает углубление в степенные функции? ;)

Answer (score 2):

*VBA-UDF*

```
Function fExp_(dNum As Double, Optional exp As Long = 2) As Double
    Dim x As Double: x = dNum
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To exp: x = x * dNum: Next i
    fExp_ = x
End Function
```

В ячейку:

```
=fExp_(4;5)
```

Или вызвать из процедуры:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print fExp_(4, 5)
End Sub
```

В такой записи результат = 4^5. Без указания степени число возводится в квадрат

```
=fExp_(4)
```

Вместо числа можно сослаться на ячейку с числом.

Comment: Зачем брать логику из ответа, который автор уже принял, и просто обернуть его в функцию?

Comment: @Вадим Александру, функция написана на *VBA* без копирования логики из Вашего ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было сказано в комментариях, можно для целой степени. Вот пример для положительной степени.
Учитывая что 2^3 = 2 * 2 * 2 можно написать такой код:

```
Dim base As Integer = 2
Dim number As Integer = 1
Dim power As Integer = 3
Dim i As Integer

for i = 1 to power
   number *= base
Next i   

Console.WriteLine(number)
```

Comment: А вопрос по VBA... Вы уверены, что это там работает?

Comment: Где тамтработает?

Comment: Вопрос по **Visual Basic for Applications**. Там - это в редакторе  *VBA*. Или *fryboil* обрадовался решению из-за незнания, или метка, заголовок темы и текст написаны некорректно

Comment: Код на VBA я не понимаю, что вас смущает

Comment: Вопрос-то по VBA! Посмотрите метку. Посмотрите заголовок. Там не С++, не Асемблер, не 
Python - там VBA......

Comment: Так я код предоставил на vba! В чем проблема??! Убедитесь сначала что я не прав прежде яем такую глупость писать!!

Comment: @vikttur пожалуйста, будьте конструктивнее. Уточните, почему данный код не заработает в VBA?

Comment: @Вадим Александру, странно... Вы пишете, что код на VBA не понимаете, но в следующем комментарии - что предоставили код на VBA. У нас разный VBA? В редакторе VBA-Excel запись.`Dim base As Integer = 2` некорректна.. Надо или `Dim base As Integer:  base = 2`, или константой:  `Const base As Integer = 2`. `Console` воспринимается не как оператор, а как переменная. Результат можно вывести в окно *Immediate* - `Debug.Print Number` Такое тоже не воспринимается: `number *= base`

Comment: @Вадим Александру, моя функция у Вас работает?