# Вычисление факториала числа 6 на VBA

Tags: циклы, vba

Только начал изучать `VBA` в университете, не знаю как решить вот эту задачу: *Используя оператор цикла `for` вычислить значение факториала числа 6:*

```
Sub Task7()
Dim i As Single, s As Single
For i = 1 To 6 Step 1
  i = i + 1
  s = i ^ 2
Next i
MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207071/Возвести-число-в-степень-не-используя-операцию-возведения-в-степень-с-помощью. Вам нужно вместо возведения в степень определить файториал. Изучайте )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот пример [отсюда](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/numbers/factorials.htm)

```
Public Function Factorial(ByVal iValue As Integer) As Long 
Dim fact As Long 
Dim icount As Integer 
   fact = 1 
   For icount = 1 To iValue 
      fact = icount * fact 
   Next icount 
   Factorial = fact 
End Function
```

если сделать подобное у вас

```
Sub Task7()
Dim i As Single, s As Single
s = 1;
For i = 1 To 6 Step 1
   s = i * s
Next i
MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Comment: а можно как-то попроще? просто мне вообще не понятно что это вы написали, да и проверяющий поймет, что я такое бы сам не написал

Comment: Так сойдет?????

Comment: да, спасибо!!!!